# How do I convert a Collection of Elements into the "Current Selection" in Revit?

Tags: c#, revit-api

I am trying to create a "smart filter" that works similarly to the Revit "filter", but grouping elements in other ways (such as family type, or workset, or level, or even "Mark").  It is simple enough to create collections isolating these parameters, but I can't seem to exit my program with the document.selection modified to include ONLY the elements I had left "checked".

My program is able to manipulate the remaining "checked" elements, such as "Hide In View", or "Halftone" or "Delete" -- but the list of possible operations to be done to the resulting selection is too long to have them all included in my Dialog form -- I want an option to simply pick a radio button that says "Set Selection", and have the program exit with THOSE elements in the selection.

I have tried:

```
doc.Selection.Elements.Add(Element *****);
doc.Selection.Elements.Remove(Element *****);
```

These return the error "not at instance of an object".

When you finish with Revit's "Filter", the result is a modified Selection.  Is there a way to do the same thing in a C# Add-in?

Comment: Which version of Revit?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it in the UI Document.

```
SelElementSet selElements = uidoc.Selection.Elements;
selElements.Add(element);
```

This code works for me.

Comment: Thank you....the real key was the SelElementSet.....I had tried to port the elements into a Selection, but there are more variable types than I was aware.  The doc.Selection.Elements in my original question was in fact the same one in your example.  After using SelElementSet (and making sure it was clear), I was able to loop through all elements I wanted in the final selection and .Add(Element).

Comment: This is the correct answer here. UIDocument supports setting selection. How you obtain the elements to feed into that selection set is totally up to you. To filter by a parameter value look at `FilteredElementCollectors` and all Filters that they support. Also, please accept an answer if you like one.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be the Revit isn't looking directly at the object when you reference the element - have you tried using the elementID instead? Or the element.UniqueID?